# Sending a constant parameter to concoridion execute call.

Tags: java, concordion

I need to - don't ask my why - send constants to a concordion call from HTML.

Instead of something like this

```
concordion:execute="sayHello(#name)"
```

I need to be able to send it a constant

```
concordion:execute="sayHello(partha)"
```

Partha is my name. It is not the variable containing the name. It is the name itself. I have tried putting 'Partha'. But that does not work either.

There has to be some way to be able to send constants - or so I think. Could someone point me the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

I would ask you to rethink why you want to do this. By using a constant in the specification, it would not be visible in either the output specification or the code.

If the constant is important to describe the scenario then it should be visible in the specification, and set using concordion:set. If it's not important to the scenario then it should be implemented in the instrumentation. For example, using the following in the specification:

```
concordion:execute="sayHelloToPartha()"
```

and creating a sayHelloToPartha() method (which might just delegate to sayHello("Partha"))

Concordion deliberately restricts the expressions that can be used in the instrumentation, to steer people towards using good practices. However, if you want to remove this restriction you can apply the annotation @FullOGNL to your fixture class. This would probably allow for constant values to be passed in expressions, should you so wish.

Comment: <span concordion:execute="setCurrentTime(#TEXT)">09:00AM</span> #TEXT  contains the text of the current element